# Bitmapfont on stage

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a stage and It has a rectangular image which covers the half of screen. I put a bitmapfont which shows "Highscore: " but when I add this font to the stage, the font stays behind the image and hard to see... I want it to come in front of that image but how can I do it ?

Comment: Scene2D objects are drawn in the order added so the newest ones are on top. Add the score to the stage last.